# Dividing line image between unordered list items

Tags: html, css

I am using an unordered list as a vertical navigation bar, and am trying to have an image as a separating line between each element, in addition to one above and below the list.

I am using the following css

```
ul>li{
    display:block; 
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul>li:before{
    content:url(http://s21.postimg.org/eonynopdv/divider.jpg);
}

ul>li:last-child:after{
    content:url(http://s21.postimg.org/eonynopdv/divider.jpg);
}
```

To place an image which is 2px high between each element although it goes inline with the list items. Is it possible to style these images so they appear above and below correctly?

[Example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p7wsuppp/)

Comment: use a `background-image` instead [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/p7wsuppp/1/)

Comment: I tried this approach, but that way could only have one of the above/below images and not both

Comment: check the fiddle i have attached above

Comment: The use of inline-block in your example kept the lines inline with the text. Changing these to block made it work as I wanted - so thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this css here:

```css
ul>li{
    border-top:10px solid;
    list-style-type: none;
    border-image:url(http://s21.postimg.org/eonynopdv/divider.jpg) 30 30;
}
ul>li:first-child{
    border-top:0 none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0b5vau42/1/

Answer (score 1):

I always prefer to use :after and :before to create some additional effects

```
 ul>li:before{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background: green;
    content:'';
    left: 0;
 }
```

something like that 
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SzymonDziewonski/s2eq2tfu/)

Answer (score 0):

try css3 border image property.

```
border-image:url(image.png) 30 30 round;
```

you can apply border only on the sides you want.